# Rails 4.1: undefined method `application' for Rails:Module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssh, production

So I am trying to host a Rails 4.1 on Hostgator, and I am getting the following error when I run `rake db:migrate` in my remote rails directory after setting up `database.yml`:

```
WARNING: 'require 'rake/rdoctask'' is deprecated.  Please use 'require 'rdoc/task' (in RDoc 2.4.2+)'    instead.
    at /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rdoctask.rb
** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
rake aborted!
undefined method `application' for Rails:Module
/home2/flsintl/public_html/dev/fls/config/initializers/filter_parameter_logging.rb:4
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.18/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:171:in     `load_without_new_constant_marking'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.18/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:171:in `load'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.18/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:547:in     `new_constants_in'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.18/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:171:in `load'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.18/lib/initializer.rb:622:in `load_application_initializers'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.18/lib/initializer.rb:621:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.18/lib/initializer.rb:621:in `load_application_initializers'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.18/lib/initializer.rb:176:in `process'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.18/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `send'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.18/lib/initializer.rb:113:in `run'
/home2/flsintl/public_html/dev/fls/config/environment.rb:9
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
/usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.18/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `require'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.18/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:547:in   `new_constants_in'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.18/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:182:in `require' 
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.18/lib/tasks/misc.rake:4
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `call'  
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:205:in `execute'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:200:in `execute'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:158:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:176:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:174:in `invoke_prerequisites'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:157:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:151:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/task.rb:144:in `invoke'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:116:in `invoke_task'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `top_level'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `each'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `top_level'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `top_level'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:66:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:133:in `standard_exception_handling'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/application.rb:63:in `run'
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/bin/rake:33
/usr/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/usr/bin/rake:19
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
```

I think it is probably telling that is says rails-2.3.18 even though I rails 4.1 is in the Gemfile (or was the version on my local computer when I developed the app). But I am still confused about what to do.

Here is my Gemfile:

```
 source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.0.4'

gem 'haml'
gem 'haml-rails'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.1.1'

gem 'sqlite3'

gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.2'

gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'


gem 'stripe', :git=> 'https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ruby'

gem 'jquery-rails'

gem 'turbolinks'

gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end
```

Comment: What does your gemfile look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, as of this date, Hostgator server environment doesn't support [rails 4 applications](http://support.hostgator.com/articles/hosting-guide/hardware-software/ruby-on-rails-and-gems]), (and it's a pain to get a rails 3 app up and running).  You are going to have to either modify your app to be compatible with Rails 2.3.8 (with ruby 1.8.7), or seek a more flexible hosting option.  (I went through the same thing a couple of months ago...)